# Although my firewall is off, I cannot connect so some ports on my mac (Mountain Lion)

Tags: macos, firewall, osx-mountain-lion

I have a mac-mini (Fall 2009) with OS X 10.8.4 on my local network and I am running a simple http server on port 5000 (or any other port).

I have turned the firewall OFF. I can connect to the mac via ssh and ping it.

I can connect to the http server using

```
curl 127.0.0.1:5000 
...I get the data...
```

but if I use the IP that my local router has assigned to this mac, I cannot connect to the port. e.g.:

```
$ curl -v 192.168.178.26:5000
* About to connect() to 192.168.178.26 port 5000 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.178.26...
* Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

This does not work on the local mashine nor form a remote machine.

However this works:

```
$ ssh 192.168.178.26
Last login: ....
```

The firewall is off:

```
$ defaults read /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/com.apple.alf.plist firewallunload
0
```

and ipfw seems to be OK:

```
$ sudo ipfw show
65535 0 0 allow ip from any to any
```

Interestingly, if I run the same http-server on my MacBookPro on the same network, I can connect....

Where can the problem be? And how can I debug it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if your webserver isn't only listening on 127.0.0.1, if so set it to 0.0.0.0 to listen on all interfaces (or your network public address - 192.168.178.26) so that it can be reached from other machines on the network.

Comment: in my case I could have changed the script or set an environment variable `export PORT=0.0.0.0`